# Is $\tau(\omega )= \infty \forall \omega \in \Omega$ a stopping time?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

My guess is yes since $\{\infty \leq t \}=\phi \in \mathcal{F}_t, \forall t \geq 0$ where $\phi$ is the  empty set which is always in the sigma algebra. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: @ user3503589 : Well some authors do not allow in there definition of stopping time the value $\infty$, this has to do with the fact for example that for a Brownian motion, $B_{\infty}$ has no meaning. Best regards